# Why it is not in thead?

Tags: java, jsf

```
   <h:dataTable class="pretty" value="" var="item">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="Title">
                            <h:outputText value="Title"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="Title"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column >
                        <f:facet  name="Outstanding" class="right" >
                            <h:outputText value="Description"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText  value="Outstanding"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

The output columns are in tbody not in thead why? i want them in thead. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `<f:facet name="header">`, not `Title` or `Outstanding`. Facets that are named `header` will go into `th` cells in the `thead`. The facets' contents ("Title" or "Outstanding") will be the contents of the header cell.

Comment: but it makes then <th> i want to make tds in thead how can i do that

Comment: This might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/dataTable.html

Comment: @user2232205 As far as I know, you can't. If you really want `<td>` elements in `<thead>`, you can generate a plain HTML table using `<ui:repeat>` to loop through the rows. Or you could write a custom renderer (not recommended).